# Laravel: How to insert data on click on href link using route and controller

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

After Click On "Yes I am Sure" button data not inserting into database
Here Is my code Auth user block another user from viewing their profile.
so, i am inserting data auth username and block user username into data after click on "Yes I am Sure" but data is not inserted.

my .blade file `profile/index.blade.php`
here "Yes I am Sure" href link to go on route

```
<div class="cd-popup" role="alert">
  <div class="cd-popup-container"><br>
    <div class="content_block">Are you sure you want to block this person?</div><br>
   <div class="content_block_instruct">Hide content and notifications from this user.</div><br>
    <ul class="cd-buttons">

      <li> <a href="{{route('profile.index',['username' => $user->username])}}">Yes I am Sure!</a></li>

      <li><a href="">Cancled</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-close img-replace">Close</a>
  </div> <!-- cd-popup-container -->
</div>
```

Route File

```
Route::post('/{username}', [
    'uses' => 'Profile\UserProfileController@blockUser',
    'as'   => 'profile.index',
]);
```

Controller file 
Whose username show on URL, with their username check BlockUser model if block_username and URL username same data not inserted else data not same their data inserted into database

```
public function blockUser(Request $request, $username)
{

       $blocked = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
       if (blockuser::where('block_username', $username)->first()){

       }else{
           $blocked = new blockuser;
           $blocked->user_username = Auth::user()->username;
           $blocked->block_username = $username;
           $blocked->save();
       }

       $user = Auth::user();
       $userprofile = userprofile::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
       return view('profile.index',compact('user', 'userprofile'));
 }
```

Here is my User Model

```
  public function blockuser(){
        return $this->hasOne( BlockUser::class);
  }
```

BlockUser Model

```
use App\User;

class BlockUser extends Authenticatable
{

      public $timestamps = false;

      protected $fillable = [
        'user_username', 'block_username',
      ]; 

      public function user()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'username' );
      }
}
```

Database table `block_users`

```
id   user_username   block_username
1    
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Clicking simply on link actually makes GET HTTP Request. You need to change from`Route::post(...)` to `Route::get(...)`. If you still want to have post method, then make simple ajax call with post method on onclick event of the anchor tag.